# Can not login or change password in Ubuntu, spread user, created by Vertica installation script

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, vertica

Spread user is created by Vertica installation script. I tried to login to spread, changing the password for the spread user. But was not successful.

Can anyone please give some additional info regarding the problem that I am facing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please at least mention why you are voting down this question, so that it will help me improve my understanding & my questioning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spread is created by Vertica: https://my.vertica.com/docs/6.1.x/HTML/index.htm#20315.htm

It is used to run the daemon spread, which is used for inter-node communication (network resilient messaging service). It is a critical block of Vertica.

Comment: Hey, thanks Guillaume. I was searching this from last day but didn't find any clue. Silly guys don't know the answer & just put vote down. Anyways, Thanks alot again.

Comment: Do you have any idea about the spread user default Password ?

Comment: This is a non-login user, so without password. You can confirm that by checking /etc/shadow.

Answer (score 1):

As for HP Vertica 7.0 spread is bundled into Vertica Server !! So less problems !!

Comment: So visually there is no spread user. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes , the daemon is there but no separate service needs to be configured ! Makes administration much easier

Answer (score 1):

just to make it more clear for you :

Hadoop has nothing to do with the spread process! before version 7 or after.
Spread is a tool for messaging and group communication.

[host_vertica]$ ps -ef | grep spread
dbadmin   7220     1  0 Jan02 pts/2    00:01:38 /opt/vertica/spread/sbin/spread -c /home/dbadmin/VMart/v_vmart_node0002_catalog/spread.conf
dbadmin  29576 22865  0 11:48 pts/1    00:00:00 grep spread

**You can see the dbadmin user is the processes owner.**

Hope it helped.